# Why does Terraform Registry not find public repos from GitHub organization?

Tags: github, terraform, terraform-cloud, terraform-modules, terraform-registry

So my GitHub organization has granted "No private access" to the Terraform Registry.

[image: Screenshot of OAuth grants page for Terraform Registry]

Then, why does it cause Terraform to not see the public repositories from my organization?

[image: Screenshot of Terraform Registry showing no repostories in the list]

I think Terraform Registry should be able to access public repositories from GitHub orgs without needing to provide private access.

Why does Terraform Registry not find public repos from GitHub organization?

Comment: Is this linked to https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/311?

Comment: i suppose not..